# Can't solve a differential equation $xdy-2ydx+xy^2(2xdy+ydx)=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given an equation:

> $$xdy-2ydx+xy^2(2xdy+ydx)=0$$

I've tried a lot to group the dx and dy multipliers, but haven't proceed to at least go further in my solution, so I need help.

Comment: are $x$ and $y$ independent variables, or how they are related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use
$$
2xdy+ydx = \frac1yd(xy^2)
$$
and
$$
xdy-2ydx = x^3\,d(x^{-2}y)
$$
and express the remaining coefficients in terms of $u=xy^2$ and $v=x^{-2}y$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
One way is finding integrating factor, so with
$$(-2y+xy^3)dx+(x+2x^2y^2)dy=0$$
$M=-2y+xy^3$ and $N=x+2x^2y^2$, then
$$p(z)=\frac{{M}_{y}-{N}_{x}}{Ny-Mx}=\frac{-(3+xy^2)}{xy(3+xy^2)}=\dfrac{-1}{xy}=\dfrac{-1}{z}$$
therfore
$$I=e^{\int p(z)\ dz}=\dfrac{1}{z}=\color{blue}{\dfrac{1}{xy}}$$
is integrating factor.